How do I trigger an external vanilla JS function from within a React component?
I am building an application in React and placing it on a page on my site.
I have a 3rd party chat widget/plugin on my site and would like it to be activated when a particular button is clicked from within my React component. In vanilla JS this is usually done with the following function:
LiveChat.openChatWindow();

However, I cannot figure out now to call this function from within my react component.
I've tried
  const launchChat = () => {
    LiveChat.openChatWindow();
  }
// Other code

  <a class="btn chat-btn" onClick={launchChat}>Chat to us</a>

But the application wont compile because, of course, LiveChat is not defined (on my local machine).
I cannot seem to launch the chat by detecting a click from outside the component either, because, of course, the button is created by React, and not in the DOM.
$(function(){
  $(".chat-btn").click(function(){
    LiveChat.openChatWindow();
  });
});

Would anyone know how I should be going about this?

What is LiveChat supposed to be / where is it meant to come from? Why isn't it defined?

You can grant the LiveChat to window scope and in React component just access it from window.
This is the example code:

Where you declared the LiveChat variable

window.LiveChat = ...


In the react component

const launchChat = () => {
  window.LiveChat.openChatWindow();
}

